# PHP Memcached unserialization of stored value returns __PHP_Incomplete_Class

Tags: php, memcached

I have the following code in an existing application:

```
if(!($article = $this->memcached->get('article_'.$articleId))) {
    $article = $this->model->ArticleManager()->getStoryById($articleId);
    $this->memcached->set('article_'.$articleId, $article);
}
```

No, when $article is retrieved from the ArticleManager it's of the correct type, it's a namespaced object \Site\Articles\Article() to be exact. However, when  this value is stored in memcached and returned on the next page load the object is of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class. Which I know means it can't find the original class, but why...?

The file this call is in is under the namespace \Site\index\default_Read_Controller().

Comment: Because you haven't included the class specification specifically for that 2nd request, and there isn't an `autoload` defined which can find it. (The class definition is _not_ stored with the object data, you need to have that loaded or autoloadable on retrieval).

Comment: @Wrikken: it's an answer

Comment: Ah yes, was not that dedicated yesterday. I'll upgrade it to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't included the class specification specifically for that 2nd request, and there isn't an `__autoload` (or a preferred `spl_autoload_register()`) defined which can find it. The class definition is not stored with the object data, you need to have that loaded or [autoloadable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) on retrieval, or defined explicitly: see the remarks at [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)(which is the function variables usually go through if stored outside the php request):

> It's possible to set a callback-function which will be called, if an undefined class should be instantiated during unserializing. (to prevent getting an incomplete object "__PHP_Incomplete_Class".) Use your php.ini, ini_set() or .htaccess to define 'unserialize_callback_func'. Everytime an undefined class should be instantiated, it'll be called. To disable this feature just empty this setting.